# why does this code return true only for the super user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

this code in theory should stop user without the mentioned permission. could it be a caching issue as i have found posts on github with this issue but from a different version of django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import chem

# Create your views here.


def console(request):
    if request.user.has_perm('bio_lab.can_view_chem'):
        print('works')
        istekler = chem.objects.all()
        return render(request,'console.html',locals())
    else:
        print('error')
'''
```

Comment: Caching of permission is only applicable to dynamically created permissions and checking of permissions in the same request response cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user who is **superuser** and is **active**, assumed to have all the permissions -- this is by design.

Here's the source code of [`User.has_perm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L281):

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):

    # Active superusers have all permissions.
    if self.is_active and self.is_superuser:
        return True

    # Otherwise we need to check the backends.
    return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)
```

Comment: this does work for the super user but any other user with the permissions returns false.